# Variable of parent component not access in child component

Tags: angular6

I need to check this loaded variable is true or false in my RolesComponent.

But I am getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
```

These are the codes I have tried

### Users

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-users',
    templateUrl: './users.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

    events = [];
    loaded:boolean = false;

    constructor(private _eventService: UserService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._eventService.getEvents()
            .subscribe(
                res => {
                    this.events = res;
                    this.loaded = true;
                    console.log(this.loaded);
                },
                err => console.log(err)
            );
    }
}
```

### users.component.html

```
<div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{ event.name }}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{ event.description }}</p>
```

### Roles

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersComponent } from '../events/users.component';

export class RolesComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(UsersComponent) event;

  constructor() { }
  loaded: boolean;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.event.loaded);
    this.loaded = this.event.loaded;
  }

}
```

### roles.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngIf="loaded">
```

Comment: Please share your HTML. Looks like you have not added child selector in HTML.

Comment: @VishwPatel yes i dont know about child selector in HTML. I want to show roles html only if loaded is true.. i have <div class="wrapper" *ngIf="loaded"> in my roles.component.html

Answer (score 0):

@ViewChild is used to refer Child Component inside Parent Component.

@ViewChild will look for the reference of Child component inside Parent Component.

You have to make sure in Parent HTML, you have used Child selector you have defined for Child component. You have to write this so that if will map your @ViewChild object with this component.

So just make sure you have added child selector in parent HTML.

If you have written same in HTML, there might be loading sequence issue.

Comment: I could not figure out in my case

Comment: Can you share your full both components ts and HTMLs ?